# mysql only execute insert if values exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

There are a few questions that look a lot like the question below, but i can't find a proper answer.
I want to do an insert in table b, for example ID_b,ID_a, name, name2.
I only want to do the insert if the ID_a exists in table a

Simple question, leading to a headache.

Comment: Basically you need to do 2 queries.  Check if it exists first if it does execute your insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single insert-select statement for this.

E.g., assume your values for [ID_b, ID_a, name, name2] are [1, 100, 'name', 'name2']:

```
INSERT INTO b (ID_b, ID_a, name, name2)
SELECT 1, ID_a, 'name', 'name2'
FROM   a
WHERE  ID_a = 100
```

If `ID_a = 100` exists, the new row will be inserted. If it does not, zero rows will selected from table `a`, and thus, nothing will inserted into `b`.